# How can I run next.js localhost and prisma studio at same time?

Tags: node.js, next.js, prisma

Im pretty new to next.js, node and prisma, so please don't rage at me if it is a real basic question. I still didnt find a solution.

So I'm running my dev environment by writing `npm run dev`. It goes to `localhost3000`. Now if I run `npx prisma studio`, I have my instance on `localhost5000`, but I cant get it work running both of them in the same time.

I tried doing this: https://itnext.io/4-solutions-to-run-multiple-node-js-or-npm-commands-simultaneously-9edaa6215a93 but without any success. The packages didnt install even.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use start in front of each command so it starts a new instance

```
    "dev": "start next dev & start npx prisma studio",
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `concurrently` to start several processes together.

https://github.com/open-cli-tools/concurrently

```json
"start": "concurrently \"command1 arg\" \"command2 arg\""
```

```json
"dev": "concurrently \"start next dev\" \"start npx prisma studio\""
```